# Esp8266 not responding to GET request from Android app created using MIT App Inventor

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, web-server, android

I hope I am posting this question in the right section.
I am making a Smart Home Project for my college semester finals. I am using an Atmega328p microcontroller along with an ESP8266 (Esp 01). The Atmega328p controls all the sensors and actuators and sends the data to Esp01 via serial communication.

I have created a web server on the Esp01 which I plan to access by creating an app using MIT App Inventor. My GET request is of the format "http://192.168.43.42/4" where the digit at the end is data I want to send to the server and the response I get from the server is of the format "12&0&34.8" where the '&' is used to separate different values.

My problem is , when I access the server from Chrome in my laptop I get the desired response but when I access it using the App , I get an error "Error 1101 :Cannot find the specified URL". The Esp01 is connecting to a hotspot from my phone and I have checked the IP assigned to the Esp01 to ensure my GET request is correct.

The code for Esp01 in Arduino IDE is here : https://gist.github.com/TheMagicSmoke/467d6227d670697464038056e22f302d

The blocks for the app made in App Inventor is below:
[image]

[image]

The GET request URL when entered from Chrome in laptop returns a blank page at first but upon refreshing Chrome I get the desired response I told earlier. And in the app , I have used a timer which queries the server with the same GET request every 2 seconds. But when I open the App the error keeps on popping up. Please suggest me a solution, I have googled this without any success.

Comment: Is MIT AppInventor something that runs locally on a device or computer on your network, or something that runs on a website somewhere?

Comment: I have edited the title as it seemed misleading. What I meant is that I am accessing the server using an Android app that was created using MIT App Inventor which is a website.

Comment: I'm finding it hard to find any concrete information, but it looks like the "app" on your phone may just be a front-end to the MIT web servers and the code actually runs on there, not your phone - which means that the code can't get at what is inside your network - only things that are on the internet.

Comment: You have misunderstood. The server is a local server which has been created on the esp8266. The application on my phone is sending a GET request to that server. Both my phone and the Esp8266 are on the same WiFi network. This has nothing to do with the servers at MIT.

Comment: No, *you* misunderstand. Like I said, I am not certain, but I *think* that AppInventor works like this:  1. you design your app. 2. the interface is displayed on your phone. 3. Interactions are sent from your phone to MIT. 4. MIT executes code. 5. MIT attempts to connect to your ESP8266. Your ESP8266 is not on the internet, and MIT is not on your local network, so MIT cannot connect to it.

Comment: I would suggest using some third-party communication system, such as MQTT (if AppInventor supports it), or switching to a real programming language that runs directly on your phone.

Comment: Is the phone on WiFi in the same network as the esp-01? (@Majenko, I helped here on SE with a project with App Inventor and there was no problem to access a local esp-01)

Comment: @Juraj `The Esp01 is connecting to a hotspot from my phone`

Comment: did you try to access the page from a browser on the phone?

Comment: @Majenko the Applications created using MIT App Inventor run code locally on the mobile and not through MIT servers. I am sure about this. Thank you for helping me. I have found out the solution and will post it below as an answer.

Comment: @Juraj thank you for helping me. I have found out the solution and will post it below as an answer.

Comment: Can Yo post. aia file? Many thx in advance.
Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found out the solution to this problem. The code that I had written in the Arduino IDE for the Esp8266 was not correct for handling the GET request.  It only accepted data as a simple Web Server and not as a HTTP server. I am posting the modified code below .

https://gist.github.com/TheMagicSmoke/adaae1e4d92f258c88184c8690e68f08

Comment: so I didn't look at your code (the first version). I expected that you used the WiFiWebServer example not a sketch, which expects data 10 milliseconds after connect, else it fails